# Using the Windows 10 IoT Core Raspberry Pi 2 Onboard UART for serial io?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

The current Windows 10 IoT core (V 10.0.10240, Sept 2015) claims not to have tested the Raspberry Pi 2B on-board UART (physical P1 pins 8=tx, 10=rx) for serial io. Here is the list of officially supported I/O: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm

Has anybody gotten this on-board UART Serial IO to work with Windows 10 IoT? Tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The October insider release has the onboard serial enabled. I have modified the serial example and have had mixed results so far. One issue that it has seems to be that if data is being sent to the pi while the port is being initialized, it throws an exception. Trying to work around it for now.

Comment: Thanks! Please keep us posted on progress or let us know where to follow.

Comment: Link to thread on issues having with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339074/windows-10-iot-serial-working-on-rp2-but-read-serial-data-incomplete